# How to sort by field using ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

I have a queryset of all objects in the Room model.
qs = Rooms.objects.all()
I need to sort it by the last received message in the Message table. There I have a variable room, which has a FK relation to Room.
I.e. the last created Message object, should act as 1 Room, the penultimate should go second, etc.
How can I in Room refer to timestamp for sorting?
qs.order_by("message_room__timestamp")
I tried to do qs.order_by("message_room__timestamp"), but for some reason I get a very strange response, I get duplicate rooms

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class Message(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, related_name="message_room")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because it will make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on `Message`, and thus for each `Message`, return the `Room` once, and thus the same room can occur multiple times.

You can annotate with the largest timestamp, so:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Room.objects.alias(
    latest_message=Max('message_room__timestamp')
).order_by('latest_message')
```